# How do I create a recursive infix parser that does not hang?

Tags: haskell

Consider this code:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

prefixExpr :: ReadP Int
prefixExpr = choice [readPlus, readS_to_P reads]
  where
    readPlus = do
        string "+ "
        s1 <- prefixExpr
        string " "
        s2 <- prefixExpr
        return $ s1 + s2

p $. s = case [ x | (x,"") <- p `readP_to_S` s ] of
    [x] -> Right x
    [ ] -> Left "mkRead: no parse"
    _   -> Left "mkRead: ambiguous parse"
```

It works great!

```
λ prefixExpr $. "+ 1 + 2 3"
Right 6
```

But this variant does not:

```
infixExpr :: ReadP Int
infixExpr = choice [readPlus, readS_to_P reads]
  where
    readPlus = do
        s1 <- infixExpr
        string " + "
        s2 <- infixExpr
        return $ s1 + s2
```

Actually, it hangs.

```
λ infixExpr $. "1 + 2 + 3"
^CInterrupted.
λ infixExpr $. "1"
^CInterrupted.
```

I understand that `infixExpr` enters infinite recursion trying to decide whether "1" is a number
or the start of an expression, but I wonder how I can prevent that. I do not really need my
program to explore all the possibilities indefinitely, just to pick the most obvious one and disregard
the others altogether. How can I do that?

One thing I tried is to put a restriction on the recursive depth.

```
infixExpr :: Int -> ReadP Int
infixExpr 0 = number
infixExpr n = choice [plus, number]
  where
    plus = do
        s1 <- infixExpr (n - 1)
        string " + "
        s2 <- infixExpr (n - 1)
        return $ s1 + s2
```

It kind of works, but it is practically useless because of its exponential complexity.

Comment: You need to remove left-recursion in your LL grammar, through a suitable factorization. Google should provide some examples.

Comment: @chi Nice, it works!

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @chi, removing left recursion through factorization:

```
infixExpr :: ReadP Int
infixExpr = number >>= \x -> choice [plus x, eof >> return x]
  where
    plus x = do
        string " + "
        y <- infixExpr
        return $ x + y
```

It works:

```
λ infixExpr $. "1"                
Right 1
λ infixExpr $. "1 + 2"
Right 3
λ infixExpr $. "1 + 2 + 3"
```

But I am a bit unhappy about it. I would rather that the original grammar was made to work, because it looks more like human thinking than this one.

---

To be fair, the same effect could be achieved easier, by a very small edit:

```
infixExpr :: ReadP Int
infixExpr = choice [plus, number]
  where
    plus = do
        s1 <- number  -- Notice!
        string " + "
        s2 <- infixExpr
        return $ s1 + s2
```

I figured it some time ago, but I really wanted to have this symmetry to the definition of `plus`.

Comment: Note that this makes + associate to the right. That doesn't really matter for +, but for - you'd get wrong results for expressions like `1 - 2 - 3` (which should be the same as `(1 - 2) - 3`, but would actually be the same as `1 - (2 - 3)` using a right-recursive grammar like that. The usual approach for left-associative operators is to parse them as a list and then left-fold that list.

Comment: @sepp2k This is all so unfortunate! Is there no better way?

Comment: "I would rather that the original grammar was made to work, because it looks more like human thinking than this one." I agree, but sadly this is a limitation of LL parsers in general. That's why libraries like [Megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) provide [reusable named combinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parser-combinators-1.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Combinators-Expr.html) for this sort of grammar. (Under the hood, Megaparsec parses the input as if the grammar were right-associative, and then reassociates it to the left as a semantic analysis.)